# Table of Contents major restyle

Tags: table-of-contents, etoc

I'm implementing a design created by someone who's never used LaTeX :)

Most of the fancy design I've managed using some Tikz picture wizardry, but I'm now in the last few percent and just can't get my head around how to implement to table of contents design.

Here's is what has been designed (apologies for cutting off the text from page 5 onwards but you get the idea):
[image: Required TOC]

Thanks to all of you wonderful people on here and my 20 year old LaTeX books I've:

- created the nonstandard ttf fonts
- Used chaprange to get the page ranges
- redefined the \chapter command to remove "chapter" and number from the \leftmark and prevent this actually being printed on the page (it's the design)

I now have the beginnings of a toc that looks like:
[image: current TOC]

with an associated toc containing lines:

```
\contentsline {chapter}{\numberline {}Introduction}{\pageref {chap:1}--\pageref {prenextchap:1}}
```

I need to de-bold the headings and change the font size of the numbers, both of which are straight forward.  However, I've seen a lot of side by side TOC styles, but I've not seen anything in my searching where the chapter title is below the page number (or range in this case).  Further more, is there a way of putting the items in a n x 2 grid?

Part of the doc is being created by Pweave and I'm already using Tikz heavily along with a fair few other packages and creating the pdf with xelatex.  I've a feeling there might be a tikz solution but don't know the toc well enough to get started.

Since the whole thing is generated using python and pweave in the first place, that's also an option.

More than happy if you can point me at another answer or package if I've missed something in my searching!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: you only need to have chapters in the TOC ?

Comment: yes only chapters in the TOC - thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a start.

I obeyed the constraint that exactly **two rows** had to be used.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{etoc}
\etocsettocdepth{chapter}

\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{array}

\newcounter{mychapcount}

\begin{document}

% first get page numbers
% for the last one, we use package lastpage

\makeatletter
\etocsetstyle{chapter}
  {}
% due to \the\numexpr\etocthepage-1
% this will only work with arabic page numbers!
%
% unfortunately, LaTeX puts in toc file only expansion of \thepage,
% losing the actual numerical page counter value. Most of the
% time, though, arabic numbers are used, so it is ok.
%
% I could similarly have used \etocthenumber to get chapter numbers
% but it would have same frailty, so better with dedicated counter
%
  {\stepcounter{mychapcount}%
   \etociffirst
    {\expandafter\xdef\csname chaprange@1\endcsname{\etocthepage-}}
    {\expandafter\xdef
     \csname chaprange@\the\numexpr\value{mychapcount}-1\endcsname
     {\csname chaprange@\the\numexpr\value{mychapcount}-1\endcsname
      \the\numexpr\etocthepage-1}%
     \expandafter\xdef\csname chaprange@\the\value{mychapcount}\endcsname
      {\etocthepage-}}%
   }
  {}
% (if one wanted to be extra sure, but TOC is typeset only
% on second pass, hence \r@LastPage will be available)
%  {\xdef\x{\x-\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\@secondoftwo
%              \csname r@LastPage\endcsname\empty}}% 
  {\expandafter\xdef
   \csname chaprange@\the\value{mychapcount}\endcsname
  {\csname chaprange@\the\value{mychapcount}\endcsname
   \expandafter\@secondoftwo\r@LastPage}}% 

\etocsettocstyle{}{}
\tableofcontents

\edef\nbofcolumns{\the\numexpr\value{mychapcount}/2}

\etocsettocstyle{\begin{center}
                 \sffamily
                 \begin{tabular}{*{\nbofcolumns}{c}}}
                {\end{tabular}\end{center}}

\setcounter{mychapcount}{0}
\def\firstcolumn{1}

\etocsetstyle{chapter}
  {}
  {\if\firstcolumn1%
        \expandafter\@gobble
   \else\expandafter\@firstofone
   \fi
   {&}%
   \stepcounter{mychapcount}%
   \gdef\firstcolumn{0}%
   \begin{tabular}[t]{p{\dimexpr(\linewidth-1cm)/\nbofcolumns\relax}}
     \bfseries\Large\@nameuse{chaprange@\the\value{mychapcount}}\\
     \etocname
   \end{tabular}
   \ifnum\nbofcolumns=\value{mychapcount}%
     \gdef\firstcolumn{1}%
     \expandafter\@firstofone
   \else\expandafter\@gobble
   \fi
   {\\[1cm]}%
  }
  {}
  {}

\etocglobaldefs

% prevent first pass
\chapter*{\contentsname}
\ifnum\nbofcolumns>0
\tableofcontents
\fi

\makeatother

\chapter{First chapter}

A

\chapter{Second chapter}

B

\chapter{Third chapter}

C
\chapter{Fourth chapter}

D

\chapter{Fifth chapter}

E

\chapter{Sixth chapter}

F

\chapter{Seventh chapter}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: on first pass, `\nbofcolumns` evaluates to `0`, hence the second `\tableofcontents` command should be avoided due to the big tabular preamble depending on it. I have thus made it conditional to `\nbofcolumns` being positive. And the `\chapter*{\contentsname}` is out of the toc style so it is always typeset even on first pass (better to stabilize page numbers earlier).

---

Only one small modification is needed to get it to work with `hyperref`: the end of the chapter style for the first `\tableofcontents` should be modified like this:

```
  {\expandafter\xdef
   \csname chaprange@\the\value{mychapcount}\endcsname
  {\csname chaprange@\the\value{mychapcount}\endcsname
   \expandafter\@secondoffive\r@LastPage}}% 

\long\def\@secondoffive #1#2#3#4#5{#2}
```

whereas the original had a `\@secondoftwo`.

And of course one needs `\usepackage{hyperref}`. Then the chapter names in the TOC will be hyperlinked. If one wants also the page ranges to be hyperlinked one needs only using `\etocthelink` :

```
   \begin{tabular}[t]{p{\dimexpr(\linewidth-1cm)/\nbofcolumns\relax}}
     \bfseries\Large\etocthelink{\@nameuse{chaprange@\the\value{mychapcount}}}\\
     \etocname
   \end{tabular}
```

---

#### Historical note:

In an earlier version of this answer I wanted to use `\etoclink`. The problem is that this (robust) macro contains the hyperref link destination in an unexpanded form. But the `&` inserted earlier closes a group, and the `hyperref` definition, which isn't global is lost. The  `\etocglobaldefs` has no effect on that.
As a result I had to completely rewrite the chapter style of the second `\tableofcontents` (i.e. the one which typesets) in order to position the group closing `&` token at the end, allowing to use `\etoclink`:

```
\setcounter{mychapcount}{0}
\newcounter{columnindex}

\etocsetstyle{chapter}
  {}
  {\stepcounter{mychapcount}%
   \stepcounter{columnindex}%
   \begin{tabular}[t]{p{\dimexpr(\linewidth-1cm)/\nbofcolumns\relax}}
     \bfseries\Large\etoclink{\@nameuse{chaprange@\the\value{mychapcount}}}\\
     \etocname
   \end{tabular}
   \ifnum\nbofcolumns=\value{columnindex}%
        \expandafter\@firstoftwo
   \else\expandafter\@secondoftwo
   \fi
   {\ifnum\value{mychapcount}=\value{columnindex}%
        \expandafter\@firstoftwo
   \else\expandafter\@secondoftwo
   \fi  {\setcounter{columnindex}{0}\\[1cm]}{}}%
   {&}%
  }
  {}
  {}
```

It does appear a bit illogical that `\etocname`, `\etocnumber`, `\etocpage` work fine without further ado even after group-closing tokens such as `&` (under the condition that `\etocglobaldefs` was issued) but that `\etoclink` has a problem (with unexpanded `\Hy@tocdestname` inside).

In fact `\etocname`, `\etocnumber`, `\etocpage` are since `etoc 1.08a 2015/03/13` the robust variants of `\etocthelinkedname`, etc..., but `\etoclink` was not made the robust variant of `\etocthelink`. Maybe it should so that the user/author does not have to recall the existence of the more obscure `\etocthelink` in the future ...

#### update:

Starting with `etoc 1.08j`, `\etoclink` behaves like `\etocname` etc..., i.e. can be used (with `\etocglobaldefs`) even if the line style has closed a group before, typically from a `&` in a tabular.

---

To get the entities centered you only need to use this:

```
   \begin{tabular}[t]{p{\dimexpr(\linewidth-1cm)/\nbofcolumns\relax}}
     \centering\arraybackslash
     \bfseries\Large\@nameuse{chaprange@\the\value{mychapcount}}\\
     \centering\etocname
   \end{tabular}
```

inside the second `\etocsetstyle{chapter}` specification. I.e. just the addition of `\centering` and `\arraybackslash`. Don't forget the `\etocthelink` also if using `hyperref` and you want the page ranges to be clickable.

[image]

---

As asked-for in comment, method for a fixed number of columns, rather than a fixed number of rows.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{etoc}
\etocsettocdepth{chapter}

\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{array}

\newcounter{mychapcount}

\begin{document}

% first get page numbers
% for the last one, we use package lastpage

\makeatletter
\etocsetstyle{chapter}
  {}
% due to \the\numexpr\etocthepage-1
% this will only work with arabic page numbers!
%
% unfortunately, LaTeX puts in toc file only expansion of \thepage,
% losing the actual numerical page counter value. Most of the
% time, though, arabic numbers are used, so it is ok.
%
% I could similarly have used \etocthenumber to get chapter numbers
% but it would have same frailty, so better with dedicated counter
%
  {\stepcounter{mychapcount}%
   \etociffirst
    {\expandafter\xdef\csname chaprange@1\endcsname{\etocthepage-}}
    {\expandafter\xdef
     \csname chaprange@\the\numexpr\value{mychapcount}-1\endcsname
     {\csname chaprange@\the\numexpr\value{mychapcount}-1\endcsname
      \the\numexpr\etocthepage-1}%
     \expandafter\xdef\csname chaprange@\the\value{mychapcount}\endcsname
      {\etocthepage-}}%
   }
  {}
% (if one wanted to be extra sure, but TOC is typeset only
% on second pass, hence \r@LastPage will be available)
%  {\xdef\x{\x-\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\@secondoftwo
%              \csname r@LastPage\endcsname\empty}}% 
  {\expandafter\xdef
   \csname chaprange@\the\value{mychapcount}\endcsname
  {\csname chaprange@\the\value{mychapcount}\endcsname
   \expandafter\@secondoftwo\r@LastPage}}% 

\etocsettocstyle{}{}
\tableofcontents

%\edef\nbofcolumns{\the\numexpr\value{mychapcount}/2}

\def\nbofcolumns{2}

\etocsettocstyle{\begin{center}
                 \sffamily
                 \begin{tabular}{*{\nbofcolumns}{c}}}
                {\end{tabular}\end{center}}

\newif\iffirstpass
\firstpasstrue
\ifnum\value{mychapcount}>\z@
  \firstpassfalse
\fi

\setcounter{mychapcount}{0}
\def\columnindex{0}

\etocsetstyle{chapter}
  {}
  {\ifnum\columnindex=\z@
        \expandafter\@gobble
   \else\expandafter\@firstofone
   \fi
   {&}%
   \stepcounter{mychapcount}%
   \xdef\columnindex{\the\numexpr1+\columnindex}%
   \begin{tabular}[t]{p{\dimexpr(\linewidth-1cm)/\nbofcolumns\relax}}
     \centering\arraybackslash
     \bfseries\Large\@nameuse{chaprange@\the\value{mychapcount}}\\
     \centering\etocname
   \end{tabular}
   \ifnum\columnindex=\nbofcolumns\space
     \gdef\columnindex{0}%
     \expandafter\@firstofone
   \else\expandafter\@gobble
   \fi
   {\\[1cm]}%
  }
  {}
  {}

\etocglobaldefs

% prevent first pass
\chapter*{\contentsname}
\iffirstpass\else
\expandafter\tableofcontents
\fi

\makeatother

\chapter{First chapter}

A

\chapter{Second chapter}

B

\chapter{Third chapter}

C
\chapter{Fourth chapter}

D

\chapter{Fifth chapter}

E

\chapter{Sixth chapter}

F

\chapter{Seventh chapter}

\end{document}
```

(I also updated the method to avoid table of contents getting executed in first pass).

[image]

Comment: I am perhaps cheating here that using only chapters, I know for sure that in book class previous chapter ended on page before (or earlier with possible blank page for openright option). Else one would need some other approach as possibly the last page of previous unit could be first one of next unit, as for sections in article class. Then it is more complicated.

Comment: this looks like it will work as chapters always start on a new page so cheating is fine :D - thanks.  I'll give this a go in the next few hours

Comment: there is `\centering` which is superfluous in `\centering\begin{tabular}{*{\nbofcolumns}{c}}`, it is a remnant from earlier code not using `center` environment.

Comment: I see there are also some superfluous `\numexpr` in `\the\numexpr\value{mychapcount}` I will remove them and the `\centering` too.

Comment: Fantastic thanks  @jfbu - implemented and does the trick.  The numbers and chapter titles aren't centering but I think that's something in my wider file causing the problem.   Thanks also for the explanations - I need to learn some of the deeper commands and this really helps.

Comment: @Yssybyl see edited answer for centering.

Comment: Perfect - I was looking in the wrong place - thank you.

Comment: Following a review the company now wants 2 columns rather than two rows ... the code works pretty much as is setting column index to 2 rather than being dynamic, but from the third row the vertical spacing is reduced.  I'm afraid I couldn't work out which bit set this spacing. TIA

Comment: @Yssybyl updated